# Number of edges in Graphical Analysis using Jupyter with Go Programming language

Tags: go, jupyter

I'm trying to learn graphical analysis in a biological setting.

The online course suggested using the Go Programming language, so I'm new to it and help to understand why **the number of edges** that I read from the following code is different than from the site I'm downloading it from.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/kortschak/graphprac"
)

infile := "YeastL.dot"
g, err := graphprac.NewGraph(infile)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to read graph: %v", err)
}
{
    fmt.Printf("G has %d nodes and %d edges.\n", g.Nodes().Len(), g.Edges().Len())
}
```

The output I'm getting is: G has 2361 nodes and 6646 edges.

But from the website http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/data/bio/Yeast/Yeast.htm it's suppose to read 7182 edges.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the [dot file in the Git repo](https://github.com/kortschak/graphprac/blob/master/YeastL.dot) has 6646 edges, the [pajek file in your link](http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/data/bio/Yeast/yeast.zip) has 7182.

Chances are the latter has been updated since.

Comment: Thats a good point @Rohit you need to contact the authors directly specifically whether an update has occurred